# Chrome home page changed

Tags: google-chrome

I don't know what happened but whenever I start Chrome this message pops up:

[image]

My home page has changed to this one:

[image]

Whenever I open a new tab, the main Google Search icon disappears and only recommended tabs are shown. The Google+ profile tab is also gone. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have fallen victim to a potentially unwanted program or other type of malware.

Enter this url into your address bar and delete everything that you don't trust or that looks suspicious, or delete everything.

```
chrome://extensions
```

Now follow these steps:

> On your computer, open Chrome.
>
> At the top right, click More  Settings.
>
> At the bottom, click Show advanced settings.
>
> Under the section "Reset settings,” click Reset settings.
>
> In the box that appears, click Reset.

from: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214

Finally head to:

```
chrome://restart/
```

Comment: ok, I did what you said, but it still did not solve the problem. Then I checked my settings and somehow the default browser had changed. i dont know how...I have uninstalled every program the I had installed since yesterday(i visited a website which emulates a nintendo gameboy[it was reccomended in a famous youtube video])..I am not having any trouble as of yet..and i CAN do a system restore but the only restore point available is before my windows update..so i will lose windows 10(which is not n option)...I think i should just wait..

Comment: oh no, when i restarted chrome, this message popped up - http://prntscr.com/cyq02p

Comment: but everything still seems to be working fine...I dont think it is malware

Comment: hm..heres what happened...some program overwrote my chrome shortcut properties to display adware..which is what was happening..now its fixed..should I still be worried?

Comment: Very interesting bit of malware. Quite bold of it to modify desktop shortcuts like that. Personally, I would still be very worried and would likely carefuly save my important data and reinstall my OS. I don't take chances with ANY kind of software which i did not explicitly install. Something that overwrites a desktop icon maliciously can also install a keylogger, or much worse.

Comment: i factory reset my PC!! Thanks for all the answers!!

Comment: Good choice, I hope you didn't get set back too far by the reset, but it's definitely the safest option to take.

Comment: nah, it helped a lot and most of the things in my laptop was junk anyway so now my laptop runs much faster :D